# How to get absolute URL's Path in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext, actionfilterattribute

I am developing an application ASP.NET Core 2.0. i have an attribute class to validation my each api request, which inherit ActionFilterAttribute class. But problem is i am not getting desired request url, the given url is coming with parameter, i need only absoluteUrl like `/api/values/get` not like `/api/values/get/1`. i think you'll get clear understanding if you see my below codes.

**Api**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("get/{id}"),AuthorizationRequiredAttribute]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationRequiredAttribute**

```
public class AuthorizationRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var url=context.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString()
    }
}
```

Comment: note that absolute URL has `protocol://domain/path` format and you really want to check only part of `path`. So it is better to edit your question.

Comment: Thanks @Set, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Contains() method help me to implement logic with given action url

```
public class AuthorizationRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var url=context.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString()
        if(url.Contains("/api/values/get/1"))
        {
             //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Request.GetDisplayURL`. This method will give complete URL. Note that the parameter is part of the URL initiated from the client so it will be shown. You will either need to remove it manually or change your URL scheme to make use of query strings.